# Rendering of asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, html

I find it hard when using asp.net controls, to make proper `css` files because I don't know what the `html` output for the different controls end up as.

For example, if I want to add a `div` tag using a asp.net control, it's not easy to know what kind of control I can use.

Are there any documentation that shows for each asp.net control, what the rendered `html` for that control will be? I understand that some controls will probably change it's output due to how it's configured, but most controls will at least follow a pattern here.

The best would of course be a service on the web where you can put in the asp.net control definition and get the rendered html out.

Currently I have to put a control into my webform, run it and check the source in the browser, and if it's not the correct html tag, try another control and repeat. That get's tedious quite fast.

Comment: I would normally use reflector to dig in to see a control or use the cssfriendly adapters but such a thing would be handy

Comment: The rendered html will even differ from browser to browser for example when ASP.Net thinks the client uses a "lower"-browser([BrowserCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx)), a Panel will be [rendered as Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx) instead of a DIV.

Comment: If you want a `div`, use a `div`. Not done much WebForms lately but I always tried to keep my ASP.NET control usage to form elements and `PlaceHolder` controls to show and hide content. I always preferred `Repeater` over any other data-oriented control, gives you maximum control over the rendered markup. And every time you use a `GridView`, a kitten doesn't just die it's tortured to a slow and painful death.

Comment: As roryf says, if you want a `<div>` use a `<div>`. Why are you trying to overcomplicate matters? You should be changing your css to fit your code, not the other way around.

Comment: @roryf and @another - The case is that I'm creating the page dynamically depending on lots of factors, so I'm generating the controls (and thereby also html) from code. Currently I'm using the HtmlGenericControl to create the div tags, and adding the content inside the div tag by using the HtmlGenericControls Controls property. Is this the perferred way, or are there any better/easier way to acccomplish this?

Comment: @Øyvind I see, not really sure what your best option is in that case, have you considered building UserControls? Ideally it should be possible to split certain UI elements into individual containers, and only supply the data that element requires.

Comment: @roryf - That is one solution of course. I'll investigate that approach further. It might clean up the code enough to be ok. I don't like the code the way it looks in it's current state ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know to what html-controls a server-control is rendered, you could call [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.rendercontrol.aspx):

```
Dim myGridView as new GridView
Dim sb as New StringBuilder()    
Dim sw as New IO.StringWriter(sb)
Dim textWriter as New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
myGridView.RenderControl(textWriter)
' now we can have a look what asp.net has rendered: '
Dim gridViewHTML as String = sb.ToString()
```

The rendered html will even differ from browser to browser for example when ASP.Net thinks the client uses a "lower"-browser([BrowserCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx)), a Panel will be [rendered as Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx) instead of a DIV.

By the way, if you're testing my above code on controls inside of your page, you have to override [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx) otherwise you get a *"...must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"*-error:

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As System.Web.UI.Control)
   Return
End Sub
```

Comment: +1: I actually got more help from the comments, but this one answers my original question, and I'll mark it as accepted for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a CssClass to your WebControls, and doing all your styling using classes, rather than HTML element types. As Tim Schmelter says, the html can render differently for different clients (I seem to remember a Panel can be a span as well under certain circumstances).

To avoid actually having to add the CssClass each time, you can subclass the WebControl you want, then set it's CssClass in Control_Init.